# Tinymce adding text with button

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to implement a button outside of the TinyMce editor, that would add text to the active editor upon clicking.
How can I do this?

(For example: There's a button on my website that should add "Test" into the editor, but it doesn't).

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code to the onClick of your button:

```
// the editor id is the same id of your textarea, default "content" in case your textarea does not have an id

tinymce.get('your_editor_id').execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "Test");
```

In case you have one single editor on your page you may also use `tinymce.activeEditor` instead of `tinymce.get('your_editor_id')`.

Comment: This is what I get: http://pastebin.com/kZPGHhP2

(The code goes trough a loop, that's why it's repeating. Also - the errors are from chrome's developer tools)

Comment: then try to use the get method to get the editor instance. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'execCommand' of null" - i guess this happens because tinymce.activeEditor is not set at that point. activeEditor gets set when the user clicks into the editor instance. If you have only one editor on your page you may also use tinymce.editors[0]